# How to delete a data in List which is not available in another List

Tags: java

Its one of my requirement. I can't post all my bean files which are more than 1000 lines of code. So, I'm just posting the sample program which exactly replica my issue.

I have a POJO class look like below:

```
  public class TestDTO {

    private String one;

    private String two;

    private String three;

    public String getOne() 
    {
        return one;
    }
    public void setOne(String one) 
    {
        this.one = one;
    }
    public String getTwo() 
    {
        return two;
    }
    public void setTwo(String two) 
    {
        this.two = two;
    }
    public String getThree() 
    {
        return three;
    }
    public void setThree(String three) 
    {
        this.three = three;
    }
```

I have a below main method which is going to set value to POJO class and store all the class object into List as below:

```
 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception 
   {
        TestDTO dto = new TestDTO();
        dto.setOne("one");
        dto.setTwo("two");
        dto.setThree("three");

        TestDTO dto1 = new TestDTO();
        dto1.setOne("one1");
        dto1.setTwo("two1");
        dto1.setThree("three1");

        TestDTO dto2 = new TestDTO();
        dto2.setOne("one2");
        dto2.setTwo("two2");
        dto2.setThree("three2");

        List<TestDTO> test = new ArrayList<TestDTO>();
        test.add(dto);
        test.add(dto1);
        test.add(dto2);

        List<String> duplicate = new ArrayList<String>();
        duplicate.add("one1");
        duplicate.add("one");

        System.out.println(test.size() + "\t before");

        for (int i = 0; i < duplicate.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < test.size(); j++) {
                if (!(test.get(j).getOne().contains(duplicate.get(i)))) {
                    System.out.println(test.get(j).getOne());
                    test.remove(j);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(test.size() + "\t after");

        for (int i = 0; i < test.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(test.get(i).getOne());
            System.out.println(test.get(i).getTwo());
            System.out.println(test.get(i).getThree());
        }

    }
```

The above code I have a `List <String>` which has some values. I just need to delete the values in `List <TestDTO>` which is not available in `List <String>`. In the above code my expected result is one, one1 are available in List so if those values are available in "dto", and "dto1" those should be still exist in the "test" list. and dto2 alone need to be deleted.

Also, I'm using JAVA 7. 
Any leads...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you want to remove the `TestDTO` object as you don't find any matching between `TestDto.getOne()` and any element of the duplicate list of String.
But what you do actually presents a logic error :

- you don't iterate on all `TestDTO` objects before to decide whether the matching is not correct. The first may not be contained but the second could.
  It is too late : you already removed it !
- you use `String.contains()` instead of `List.contains()` (probably the cause of the first point).

So I would advise you to use an iterator (simple way to  remove the current element of the iterated list) and to make a reverse in the removing condition.

This :

```
if (!(test.get(j).getOne().contains(duplicate.get(i)))) {
```

should be :

```
if (!(duplicate.contains(test.get(j).getOne()))) {
```

It would give :

```
for (Iterator<TestDTO> it = test.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    TestDTO currentTestDTO = it.next();
    if (!(duplicate.contains(currentTestDTO.getOne()))) {
        System.out.println(currentTestDTO.getOne());
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Output as expected:

> 3  before
>
> one2  <-- only one2 is removed
>
> 2  after
>
> one
>
> two
>
> three
>
> one1
>
> two1
>
> three1

Comment: It works like charm... Mucho gracious... Gonna mark this answer.

Comment: @ArrchanaMohan You are welcome :) Thanks for the quick accept.

Answer (score 3):

[retainAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection))
`java.util.List.retainAll(java.util.Collection)` - Retains only the elements in this list that are contained in the specified collection (optional operation). In other words, removes from this list all of its elements that are not contained in the specified collection.

Comment: Yes. it works. You have to override `equals` in `TestDTO`

Comment: How come a List<String> is passable to List<TestDTO>.retainAll? And 2 upvotes. Seriously?

Comment: @Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn I agree totally. Note that for a relative "long" question, reading it carefully and inspecting the code take time and I may understand that some users may read it fast and stop on "keywords" or "key concepts".  The retaining concept is not bad even if it is not straight usable in this context. It is feasible but would require some refactoring steps...

Answer (score 1):

First, prepare your duplicate string as a `Set` for faster `contains` checking:

```
 Set<String> duplicate = new HashSet<String>();
```

Then iterate over your list and filter out the duplicated:

```
 List<TestDTO> result = test.stream()
        .filter(t -> !duplicate.contains(t.getOne()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For java 7:

```
List<TestDTO> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (TestDTO t : test) {
    if (!duplicate.contains(t.getOne())) {
        result.add(t);
    }
}
// Result contains all `TestDTO` which is not in `duplicate`
```

Comment: I'm not using java 8. pls give me an idea in Java7 please.

Comment: You want to remove `TestDTO` which the `getOne()` is not in `duplicate` list right?

Comment: I just want to iterate List<TestDTO> and delete the TestDTO object from list which is not available in List<String>. For that case It needs to delete  dto2.

Comment: The result contains all items you need (not available in `List<String>`). What else do you want?

Comment: I checked but Its deleted the record which is available in duplicate. I just wanna keep those record in DTO and delete only those are not available in list

Comment: Your comment is contradict to your original code. Never mind, if you want to retains item that are available in the duplicate list then change `!duplicate.contains(t.getOne())` to `duplicate.contains(t.getOne())`